Norm surjective for unramifeid extension of local fields $L/K$
I have a question about the argument used here in proof of
Proposition 4.2.5.: For any finite unramified extension $L/K$ of local fields, the map $\text{Norm}_{L/K}: O_L^* \to O_K^*$ is surjective.
The Proof:

Say $u \in O_K^*$ is a unit. By Proposition 4.2.4, we may pick $v_0 \in O_L^*$ such that in the residue fields, the norm of $v_0$ coincides with $u$. Thus $u/\text{Norm}(v_0) \equiv 1 (\text{mod} \ \pi)$, where $\pi:=\pi_K$ is a uniformizer of $K$. Now we construct inductively units $v_i \equiv 1 (\text{mod} \ \pi^i)$ such that

$$u_i:= \frac{u}{\text{Norm}(v_0 \cdot ... \cdot v_i)} \equiv 1 (\text{mod} \ \pi^{i+1})$$: simply take $v_i$ so that $\text{Trace}((1-v_i)/\pi^i) \equiv (1-u_{i-1})/ \pi^i(\text{mod} \ \pi)$. (That’s possible because the trace map on residue fields is surjective by the normal basis theorem.) Then the product $v_0 \cdot v_1 \cdot ... $converges to a unit $v$ with norm $u$.
Question: It's not clear to me why such inductively choosen $v_i$ satisfies this congruence. Say we have already successfully constructed $v_0, v_1,..., v_{i-1}$ and want to proceed with $v_i$, which we pick as described to be those satisfying $\text{Trace}((1-v_i)/\pi^i) \equiv (1-u_{i-1})/ \pi^i(\text{mod} \ \pi)$.
Why for this $v_i$ automatically holds $\frac{u}{\text{Norm}(v_0 \cdot ... \cdot v_i)} \equiv 1 (\text{mod} \ \pi^{i+1})$? By induction and multiplicativity of norm map we get
$$ \frac{u}{\text{Norm}(v_0 \cdot ... \cdot v_i)}= \frac{u}{\text{Norm}(v_0 \cdot ... \cdot v_{i-1})} \cdot 1/\text{Norm}(v_i) \equiv \frac{1}{\text{Norm}(v_i)} (\text{mod} \ \pi^{i})  $$.
But how the inposed trace congruence
$$ \text{Trace}((1-v_i)/\pi^i) \equiv (1-u_{i-1})/ \pi^i(\text{mod} \ \pi)  $$
assures that can lift $ 1/\text{Norm}(v_i)$ to $ 1 (\text{mod} \ \pi^{i+1})$?
Philosophical note: It is interesting to note here the interplay between the field norm and the trace map in the sense that we are trying to find an element satisfying a congruence imposed in terms of norms by charcterizing it in terms of trace map.
Rmk.: I know several other proofs of this statement, the objection of this question is focussed solely to understand the "logic" of presented proof.

I think I found the answer: see proof Proposition 1.2 in Chap. III from [Milne's notes of CFT(https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/cft.html) page 98: There is lovely comm diagram relating Trace and Norm maps on filrations

I think it's a "sophisticated" version of Cassels-Frölich "Alg. Num. Th" prop9 p 29 where it is more explicit
$N(1-x\pi^n)=1+\pi^n,Trace(x)\mod\pi^{n+1}$
